# New Facebook FQL table vs. Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I just read the new User fql table fields at 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user

As I can see a lot of the fields have been deprecated such as work_history or books and movies. It is quite essential for my app to get all those fields for my user's friends in a single fql query. 
If i am not wrong the only way to do this is to get those extra fields using the Graph API by requesting them seperately for every friend of my user. Is there any way to do it in a more efficient way without so many calls?

Can I subscribe to real time updates for the request fields for my user's friends (i do not care about the logged in user data)?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had the chance to test this yet, but you can get started with the real-time updates, have a look here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime/samples/callback
http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=56610

Cheers!

Comment: hi there and thanx :)
i ve seen those but there is no word on Facebook dev sites about deprecating the extra fields from the User fql table

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is very late, but maybe this might help someone out later.

1. You cannot subscribe to friends of your application's users for changes
2. You can perform a query for information about a user's friends (assuming you have access to the data) by fetching graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=name,birthday&access_token=...